# deleting a row with a particular id in while loop

Tags: php, database, mysqli

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from movieinfo";
$sql_data = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>Movie Name</b></td>";
echo"<td><center><b>Delete</b></center></td>";
echo"</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_data,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style='color:white'>";
echo $row['title'];
echo "<td><center><a href='adminpage.php?mid={$row['movieid']}'><button 
class='contact100-form-btn' name='deletem'>Delete Movie</button></a> 
</center></td>";
$_SESSION['delete'] = $row['movieid'];
echo "<td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>


if (isset($_POST['deletem'])) {
$delete=$_SESSION['delete'];
$query6 = "DELETE FROM movieinfo WHERE movieid=$delete";
mysqli_query($db, $query6);
}
```

i need to delete the particular row with the id selected so i am storing in session the id and deleting it but when i press on the deleting button it deletes the last row only its because session is storing all the id's because of loop how should i fix it?

Comment: Obviously, you shoudn't use session here. Instead pass id of deleted record via post or get request.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * from movieinfo";
    $sql_data = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><b>Movie Name</b></td>";
            echo"<td><center><b>Delete</b></center></td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_data,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='color:white'>";
                echo $row['title'];
                **echo "</td>";
                $mid = isset($_GET['mid']) ? $_GET['mid'] : '';
                $del = "DELETE FROM movieinfo WHERE movieid=$mid";
                mysqli_query($db, $del);
                {
                echo "<td><center><a href='adminpage.php?mid={$row['movieid']}'><button 
                    class='contact100-form-btn' name='deletem'>Delete Movie</button></a> 
                    </center></td>";
                }
            echo"</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

Comment: I highly doubt this is what he wanted, as the delete can occur totally outside the loop, and mixing such dmls with presentation is somehow a bad habit.

Comment: I think, he did not know how to delete particular row in a table. So i wrote this code.